# NetGroupGetUsers returns error when group have members from other domain

Tags: winapi, active-directory, mfc

I am using [NetGroupGetUsers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/lmaccess/nf-lmaccess-netgroupgetusers) to get the members of Active Directory groups.
I have two domains and some groups have user members from both domains. When I try to list the members of this groups with mixed users, NetGroupGetUsers returns the error code 2147 (NERR_CfgParamNotFound).

Ex.:

- "DOMAIN1" has "Group1" and "user1"
- "DOMAIN2" has "user2"
- "user1" and "user2" are both members of "Group1"
- when I try to use NetGroupGetUsers to get "Group1" members it returns NERR_CfgParamNotFound
- if I remove "user2" from "Group1", NetGroupGetUsers returns Success.

This case I described is not supported or there is a way to access this data using MFC Network Management?

Exemple of how I am using NetGroupGetUsers:

```
HRESULT MySampleFunction(CString strGroupName)
{
  TCHAR tcGroup[CREDUI_MAX_USERNAME_LENGTH + 1] = { 0 };
  TCHAR tcDomain[CREDUI_MAX_DOMAIN_TARGET_LENGTH + 1] = { 0 };
  DWORD dwError = ::CredUIParseUserName(strGroupName, tcGroup, SizeOfArray(tcGroup), tcDomain, SizeOfArray(tcDomain));

  if (dwError != NO_ERROR)
    return MAKE_HRESULT(1, FACILITY_WIN32, dwError);

  GROUP_USERS_INFO_0* pGroupUsersInfo = NULL;
  DWORD dwEntriesRead = 0;
  DWORD dwTotalEntries = 0;

  NET_API_STATUS apiStatus = NetGroupGetUsers(tcDomain, tcGroup, 0, (LPBYTE*)&pGroupUsersInfo, MAX_PREFERRED_LENGTH, &dwEntriesRead, &dwTotalEntries, NULL);

  if (apiStatus != NERR_Success)
    return MAKE_HRESULT(1, FACILITY_WIN32, apiStatus);

  if (pGroupUsersInfo != NULL)
    NetApiBufferFree(pGroupUsersInfo);

  return S_OK
}
```

Comment: Show the code, how do you use NetGroupGetUsers.

Comment: NetGroupGetUsers( ) is scoped to global groups and seems that cannot be cross-domain.